# Handler is not working if created in seprate java class by extending Handler

Tags: java, android

I created a class which extends `Handler`and overrided the `handleMessage(Message)` method.
Created object in Class that extends `HandlerThead`
here is the code

```
public class WorkHandler extends Handler {

private Handler responseHandler;
private DownloadListner downloadListner;

public WorkHandler(Looper looper) {
    super(looper);
}


@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    super.handleMessage(msg);
    if (msg.what == 0) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        String url = (String) msg.obj;
        Log.i("tag", "Got a request for url: " + url);
        handleRequest(url);
    }
}

public void setResponseHandler(Handler responseHandler) {
    this.responseHandler = responseHandler;
}


public void setDownloadListner(DownloadListner downloadListner) {
    this.downloadListner = downloadListner;
}
```

here `handleRequest(url);` does the image downloading job.

```
public class DownloderThread extends HandlerThread {

public static final int MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD = 0;
private Map<String, String> mRequestMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
Handler responseHandler;
WorkHandler workHandler;

public DownloderThread(Handler responseHandler) {
    super("DownloaderThread");
    this.responseHandler = responseHandler;
}

DownloadListner mListener;

public void setListener(DownloadListner listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
protected void onLooperPrepared() {

    workHandler = new WorkHandler(getLooper());
    workHandler.setResponseHandler(responseHandler);
    workHandler.setDownloadListner(mListener);

}

public void download(String url) {
    mRequestMap.put("URL", url);
    workHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD, url).sendToTarget();
}
}
```

here the following line gives NullPointerException. Why?

```
workHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD, url).sendToTarget();
```

I am sure that it is not due to `Handler.obtainMessage()`.

Activity contains the following code

```
public class ImageDownloadActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DownloadListner {
ImageView imageView;
Button button;
Handler responseHandler;
DownloderThread thread;
String url = "http://developer.android.com/design/media/principles_real_objects.png";

boolean isThreadRunning = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_download);
    responseHandler = new Handler();
    thread = new DownloderThread(responseHandler);
    thread.setListener(this);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isThreadRunning){
                Log.i("tag","Already running");
            }else {
                Log.i("tag", "Background thread started");
                thread.start();
                thread.getLooper();
                thread.download(url);
                isThreadRunning = true;
            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onImageDownloadComplete(Bitmap bitmap) {
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    thread.quit();
    Log.i("tag", "Background thread destroyed");
    }
}
```

I also did changes in constructor of `WorkHandler` class but the result is same.
here is the stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sophomoreventure.myapplication9, PID: 12914
  java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.sophomoreventure.myapplication9.DownloderThread.download(DownloderThread.java:41)
  at com.sophomoreventure.myapplication9.ImageDownloadActivity$1.onClick(ImageDownloadActivity.java:43)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
  at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you paste the complete error stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

DownloadListener Initialization? can you check the call is made to setListener() in DownloaderThread class? Due to low reputation, posting it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Well, as no auto unboxing is involved (which could throw a `NullPointerException`), either `workHandler` or the result of `workHandler.obtainMessage(…)` is null. As you are sure it's not due to `Handler.obtainMessage(…)` it has to be because `workHandler` is null. The `workHandler` is set in `onLooperPrepared(…)`, so verify and make sure it gets called.

Side note: Never rule out something based on assumptions, always verify by testing and/or debugging. Else you can easily look and search at the wrong location…

Comment: solved the problem. Just moved the `thread.start()` and `thread.getLooper()` in `onCreate()` method.